# ¿Como extraer los datos de dos select dentro de un procedimiento con php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando una herramienta para generar reportes todo va perfecto hasta que hago una consulta a mi base mediante un procedimiento con `mysql_query`.

Si el procedimiento se ejecuta desde `MySQL Workbench`, se obtienen dos resultados (*cada uno en una pestaña distinta*).

Mi duda es como puedo obtener los datos de ambos resultados mediante `PHP`, para después poder pasarlas a arreglos mostrarlas en tablas.

Aquí dejo la sintaxis de mi `query`:

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"CALL `SGbl`.`Sp_RptResultadosBlaster`($format, 'Sol_Blaster_".$isla."','BL_".$rest."_rbt','BL_".$rest."_rbt_CM', 3);");
$array=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
```

Answer (score 2):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacer.

Define la conexion a al DB.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("ejemplo.com", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
```

Ejecuta tu consulta y valida que no hay errores.

```
if (!$mysqli->multi_query("CALL `SGbl`.`Sp_RptResultadosBlaster`($format, 'Sol_Blaster_".$isla."','BL_".$rest."_rbt','BL_".$rest."_rbt_CM', 3);")) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $mysqli->errno . " " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Luego con un ciclo `do {} while ()` puedes ir ejecutando acciones por cada resultado devuelto. En el ejemplo solo hago un `var_dump` o un `echo` en caso de error.

```
do {
    if ($resultado = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        printf("---\n");
        var_dump($resultado->fetch_all());
        $resultado->free();
    } else {
        if ($mysqli->errno) {
            echo "ERROR: " . $mysqli->errno . " " . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

Si quieres mas información puedes leer la documentación oficial: 
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: Hola, gracias me funciono mucho pero ¿como puedo utilizarlo para que el primer resultado lo pueda imprimir en una tabla y el segundo resultado lo pueda imprimir en otra tabla?

Comment: depende de como esta tu código y como lo quieras hacer. donde esta el var_dump puedes hacer echo de html (no recomendado). o puedes meter ese código en una función y en vez del var_dump vas almacenando todo el resultado en una variable y al final de do while la devuelves y manejas la creación de las tabla desde cualquier otra parte de tu código

Comment: Podria mostrarme un ejemplo?